# Can an astrologer charge money for his predictions?

Tags: puranas, astrology

I heard from someone that parashara hora shastra states that using knowledge of astrology as business is restricted and no one should charge money for it. But I never have came across such verse.

So, any shastra comment on this subject?

Comment: I don't have the text reference now,  but in samudrik Vidya text which I had read long back, it was mentioned: "one can use this knowledge for earning but only whatever the other person offers"

Comment: I remember reading (possibly its from Skanda Purana) that astrologers who earn from predictions go to hell after death .. so ideally they should not charge money but without giving Dakshina one can not take any favor too .. so some amount should be paid .. or may be some gifts like fruits etc. In any case astrologers who charge huge amount of fees surely are not doing right.

Comment: @Rickross ji If u get that reference please tell me...I also want that for some purpose. :)

Comment: Okay ... @LSSJBroly

Comment: @Rickross I have given an answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58238/24460 Were you referring to Skanda Purāṇa (1.2.39.19-20a) ?

Comment: You might be interested in it too @LSSJBroly

Comment: @Bingming I was not aware of the exact location of the verses but I vaguely remembered that I read them from Skanda Puran. Upvoted your answer for the find.

Comment: Thanks for help :) @Bingming ji

Answer (score 6):

Varāhamihira seems to not hold those daivajñas highly, who are determined in earning sampatti but lack hold in jyotiṣaśāstravidyā (like many current-day popular jyotiṣīs) -

> sampattyā yojitādeśastadvicchinakathāpriyaḥ / 
> mattaḥ śāstraikadeśena tyājyastādṛṅmahīkṣitā // 
> ~ Bṛhatsaṁhitā ([2.36](https://archive.org/details/brihat-samhita-/%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A4%20Brihat%20Samhita%20-1/page/n89/mode/2up?view=theater))

Bhaṭṭotpala, in his commentary on Bṛhatsaṁhitā (2.36), adds-

> yo daivavitsampattyā yojitādeśaḥ / sampattyā arthadānena yojita ādeśo yena / yathā pūrvamevaṁ mayā kathitametatsa devavadaiśvaryaṁ prāpsyati / taditi jyotiḥ śāstramucyate /

Skanda Purāṇa ([1.2.39.19-20a](https://archive.org/details/skanda-maha-purana-i-nag-publishers/page/n449/mode/2up?view=theater)) seems to say that a person who practices jyotiṣa as a jīvikā, attains Vaitaraṇī.

> mārjjārakukkuṭaśvānapakṣipoṣṭā prayāti ca /  badhirāndhagṛhakṣetratṛṇadhānyādijvālakaḥ //  
> nakṣatraraṅgajīvī ca yāti vaitaraṇīṁ naraḥ /

According to me, in the days of old, a daivajñā/jyotiṣī was not a person who sustained his living with jyotiṣavidyā, but one who was its viśeṣajña. They might have offered their services to Rājās, common people, etc. and the people must have given them gifts, etc. too for the services. But treating it as a profession, was perhaps not the norm in olden times.

Comment: It would be helpful if you are able to add English translations.

Comment: Can you please add English translations too in it?